# Update Email within a TriggeredSend

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send

I am finding that updating the content of an email, specifically a Content Builder email, that is set as the email in a Triggered Send DOES NOT update the content of the email sent by the Triggered Send.  It just sends the previous 'version' of the email with content as it was when originally added to the Triggered Send.

I have tried pausing then resuming the Triggered Send hoping that would trigger the send to update the email to no avail.  I have also tried search help and documentation to no avail, though I did find instructions on how to update it should it be part of a Journey -- mine is NOT part of a Journey, its a stand alone email send.

Is there a method to update the email content within a Triggered Send, preferably via Api, that will update the email sent by the Triggered Send to match the updated email content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to publish the changes to the triggered sends after you pause them for changes to be reflected

Comment: I am using the same email already linked in the Triggered Send.  Are you saying the steps would be: 1. Pause 2. Publish Changes 3. Resume?  Bear in mind I am creating the Triggered Send via Api -- can I publish changes via Soap call (I'm going to mess around with some test calls to see what results I get now, but I don't know)?

Comment: Also, after pausing I do not have the option to Publish Changes via the UI using the same email already linked.  I guess it does not see the definition as changed?

Comment: Apologies, I DO see the ability to Publish Changes once paused.  I am going to mess around with some Soap calls to see if I might be able to mimic this behavior via Api.

Comment: Check out the link below and the property "TriggeredSendStatus" in  the TriggeredSendDefinition SOAP Object. This should be what you need. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm

Comment: Update: Setting the TriggeredSendStatus to Inactive then Updating back to  Active via Soap calls DOES NOT republish the triggered send allowing it to be sent with new email content in a modified email.  Is there anything else that would allow me to republish via Api?

Answer (score 6):

In order to *republish* the TriggeredSend with updated Email content via SOAP API calls, you must specify `RefreshContent`.  I happened upon this in some generated WSDL classes -- I don't see it documented anywhere.

So the steps are (via Api):

- Update `TriggeredSendDefinition` setting `TriggeredSendStatus` to `Inactive`.
- Update `TriggeredSendDefinition` setting `TriggeredSendStatus` to `Active` and specifying `RefreshContent` as `true`.

Comment: If anyone is looking at a similar issue with send definitions for the REST Transactional API, if you [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateMessageDefinition.htm) status to 'Inactive' then update again to 'Active', this will pick up any email changes you've made.